# Only Values w/o field in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

what i've to do for getting values only (w/o field and table) from my sql DB?
For Example:
"pietro","la spada"...
I use this code

```
<?php
 // Create connection
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","DBname","","my_DBname");

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 // This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'user'
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE 1";

 // Check if there are results
 if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
 {
 // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
 // to hold the data
 $resultArray = array();
 $tempArray = array();

// Loop through each row in the result set
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    // Add each row into our results array
    $tempArray = $row;
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}

// Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

but the result includes the fields.
For Example:
"name":"Pietro","surname":"La Spada"...

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    // Add each row into our results array
    $tempArray = $row;
    $resultArray = array_merge($resultArray, array_values($tempArray));
}
```

that should be it

Comment: [null,null] is the answer from the DB with your code.

Comment: internet went down half through and as i reloaded the page blindly hit submit. The important thing is to store the return value of `array_merge`.

Comment: now the answer is  null 
Have you ever tried this code in any DB? what kind of answer have you receveid?

Comment: $a = [1];
$b = ['a' => 2];
$c = array_merge($a, array_values($b));
var_dump($c); answer: array(1,2), which is as far as i know the desired result